# Qlogic HBA issue

Tags: linux, storage

We have running server with attached SAN storage and everything was fine. However last week we moved our server blade to a new chassis. Everything is same, we just add new WWN in Brocade SAN switch to allow access of storage, but my server isn't able to see the SAN disk in `fdisk` output.

I'm seeing the following output just wondering what is wrong?

```
[root@server1 ~]# dmesg | grep qla
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Found an ISP2532, irq 82, iobase 0xffffc20010082000
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Configuring PCI space...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Configure NVRAM parameters...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Verifying loaded RISC code...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Allocated (64 KB) for EFT...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Allocated (1414 KB) for firmware dump...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: Unable to read FCP priority data.
scsi1 : qla2xxx
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0:
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Found an ISP2532, irq 106, iobase 0xffffc20010202000
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Configuring PCI space...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Configure NVRAM parameters...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Verifying loaded RISC code...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Allocated (64 KB) for EFT...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Allocated (1414 KB) for firmware dump...
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: Unable to read FCP priority data.
scsi2 : qla2xxx
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1:
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: LIP reset occured (f8f7).
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: LIP reset occured (f7f7).
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: LIP occured (f700).
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: LIP reset occured (f7f7).
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: LOOP UP detected (4 Gbps).
qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: LOOP UP detected (4 Gbps).
```

Two LOOPs? Is that OK?

```
 qla2xxx 0000:05:00.0: LOOP UP detected (4 Gbps).
 qla2xxx 0000:05:00.1: LOOP UP detected (4 Gbps).
```

#### EDIT #1:

I've added the following WWN in Brocade SAN switch for zoning:

```
[root@server1 ~]# systool -c fc_host -v | grep port_name
    port_name           = "0x2100001b329df4a9"
    port_name           = "0x2101001b32bdf4a9"
```

What is `node_name`?

```
[root@server1 ~]# systool -c fc_host -v | grep -e port_name -e node_name
    node_name           = "0x2000001b329df4a9"
    port_name           = "0x2100001b329df4a9"
    node_name           = "0x2001001b32bdf4a9"
    port_name           = "0x2101001b32bdf4a9"
```

Comment: You've got two ports, so that doesn't look strange. Make sure you got the right WWN for the port you zoned.

Comment: I have correct WWN in SAN switch `systool -c fc_host -v | grep port_name`

Comment: I have edit my question and put more info

Comment: You've talked about zoning, but not lun masking. Did you update that too?

Comment: I have checked on EMC storage side and its saying `partially active` connection status? Do i need to re-register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally problem resolved

1. shutdown server
2. de-register node in Unisphere console
3. start server
4. Add node in Storage group again
5. run `powermt config`
6. Voila!!!